# How do I create a third table from two tables?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

**I have two great tables that I would like to use as foundation for an even greater third table!**

The output depends on date interval, like 09/01/2010 - 09/03/2010

Example of Output from **TABLE A**   - -  (**ALLOCATED** Testers)

```
Date            Country        Allocated testers
09/01/2010      Nigeria           0
09/02/2010      Nigeria           1
09/03/2010      Nigeria         134

09/01/2010      China             2
09/02/2010      China             0
09/03/2010      China            14

09/01/2010      Chile             3
09/02/2010      Chile             4
09/03/2010      Chile             0

*************
```

Example of Output from **TABLE B**   - -  (**ABSENT** Testers)

```
Date            Country        Absent testers
09/01/2010      Nigeria           0
09/02/2010      Nigeria           7
09/03/2010      Nigeria           0

09/01/2010      China             2
09/02/2010      China             0
09/03/2010      China             0

09/01/2010      Chile             1
09/02/2010      Chile             0
09/03/2010      Chile             0

*************
```

Example of WANTED output from TABLE C  (ALLOCATED AND ABSENT Testers)

```
Date            Country        Allocated testers    Absent testers
09/01/2010      Nigeria           0                 0
09/02/2010      Nigeria           1                 7
09/03/2010      Nigeria         134                 0

09/01/2010      China             2                 2
09/02/2010      China             0                 0
09/03/2010      China            14                 0

09/01/2010      Chile             3                 2
09/02/2010      Chile             4                 0
09/03/2010      Chile             0                 0
```

And here is some SQL code generating the above shown output... (yes, they work)

**TABLE A**

```
WITH Calendar AS (SELECT     CAST(@StartDate AS datetime) AS Date
     UNION ALL
     SELECT     DATEADD(d, 1, Date) AS Expr1
     FROM         Calendar AS Calendar_1
     WHERE     (DATEADD(d, 1, Date) < @EndDate))
    SELECT     C.Date, C2.Country, COALESCE (SUM(R.[Amount of people per day needed]), 0) AS [Allocated testers]
     FROM         Calendar AS C CROSS JOIN
                            Country AS C2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            Requests AS R ON C.Date BETWEEN R.[Start date] AND R.[End date] AND R.CountryID = C2.CountryID
     GROUP BY C.Date, C2.Country OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**TABLE B**

```
WITH Calendar AS (SELECT     CAST(@StartDate AS datetime) AS Date
     UNION ALL
     SELECT     DATEADD(d, 1, Date) AS Expr1
     FROM         Calendar AS Calendar_1
     WHERE     (DATEADD(d, 1, Date) < @EndDate))
    SELECT     C.Date, C2.Country, COALESCE (COUNT(PA.PeopleID), 0) AS [Absent testers]
     FROM         Calendar AS C CROSS JOIN
                            Country AS C2 INNER JOIN
                            Roles AS R INNER JOIN
                            People AS P ON R.RolesID = P.RolesID ON C2.CountryID = P.CountryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            PeoplesAbsence AS PA ON C.Date BETWEEN PA.StartDate AND PA.EndDate AND P.PeopleID = PA.PeopleID
     WHERE     (R.Role = 'Tester')
     GROUP BY C.Date, C2.Country OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**TABLE C** is the one I need help to create :-)

NOTE: I would like to see some kind of example code, to get started!

NOTE ALSO: I don´t want to solve this with Views in SQL Server, because it just doesn´t work... - I need that 3:rd table ;-)

---

**SOLVED!** Got the solution from **tdammers** (thanks!), and this is how it looks when implemented:

```
WITH Calendar AS (SELECT     CAST(@StartDate AS datetime) AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATEADD(d, 1, Date) AS Expr1
FROM
    Calendar AS Calendar_1
WHERE
    (DATEADD(d, 1, Date) < @EndDate))


SELECT a.Date, a.Country, a.[Allocated testers], b.[Absent testers] FROM ( SELECT
    C.Date, C2.Country, COALESCE (SUM(R.[Amount of people per day needed]), 0) AS [Allocated testers]
FROM
    Calendar AS C
CROSS JOIN
    Country AS C2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Requests AS R 
    ON
        C.Date BETWEEN R.[Start date] AND R.[End date] AND R.CountryID = C2.CountryID
GROUP BY
    C.Date, C2.Country ) as a LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT     C.Date, C2.Country, COALESCE (COUNT(PA.PeopleID), 0) AS [Absent testers]
     FROM         Calendar AS C CROSS JOIN
                            Country AS C2 INNER JOIN
                            Roles AS R INNER JOIN
                            People AS P ON R.RolesID = P.RolesID ON C2.CountryID = P.CountryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            PeoplesAbsence AS PA ON C.Date BETWEEN PA.StartDate AND PA.EndDate AND P.PeopleID = PA.PeopleID
     WHERE     (R.Role = 'Tester')
     GROUP BY C.Date, C2.Country ) as b ON a.date = b.date AND a.country = b.country
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table C shouldn't be a table, but rather a view.

Comment: Oh wait, forget that. The first two aren't tables either, they're just select queries. I don't think you actually know what an SQL table is in the first place.

As to your original problem:
 - create a view from the first query
 - create a view from the second query
 - use a `join` on both views to accumulate the desired output for query C

Comment: OK - I admit that they are select queries! I was just joking before. The trouble is that I want a THIRD select query, not views. Because I can´t create views of them since they contains parameters, instead I have to create User-Defined-Functions, and that to me seems like to much right now - so give me a tip on how the third query should be designed and stop talking about Views! ;-) And I actually know what an SQL table is, the problem was that I didn´t know what it wasn´t - but thanks for sorting that out. I will never call a select query a table again, I promise!

Comment: Right. Instead of putting the first two queries into views, you can put them into subqueries, and perform a join on those. Although your queries seriously suggest a pretty bad database design - with a properly normalized schema, this would be ridiculously easy.

Comment: Well, I don´t agree on that "pretty bad database design" opinion - but aside from that, would you mind showing an example IN CODE of the ridiculously easy sub-query operation you suggest? That would make things a bit easier to me, and I´m sure you want to help me...? You don´t have to dig into my example, just show me something "generic" if you so prefer :-)

Comment: Something like:

SELECT a.date, a.country, a.num, b.num
FROM ( /* first subquery here */ ) as a
INNER JOIN ( /* second subquery here */ ) as b
ON a.date = b.date AND a.country = b.country

Comment: Thanks tdammers, it worked!!! - see my updated Question to see the result if interested.
One problem left though, might not be possible to fix, as it has to do with the db-design ;-) The thing is that the WHERE clause sorts out countries that have no Absent people, and I want to show them to in the output list - any ideas on workarounds? And again, a big thank you!

Comment: Does anyone (for example tdammers...) know if there is any easy way to sum "a.num, b.num" up in a fifth column? Like SUM(a.num + b.num) in the SELECT statement?

Comment: Exactly like that, just without the SUM().